# Apply bevel or insert loop cuts without affecting shading

Tags: shaders, bevel, loop

It should be an easy answer, but I can't find it.
I'm trying to add loop cuts into my shape (I can't use subsurf, as it will affect other geometry), or bevel edges, but I can't keep the shape shaded smooth, as my actions create visible areas of shade changes. Same result I get after adding loop cuts with 0.5 smoothness.
How can I make this done without those steps in shading?
Thank You!
Screen shots below:

1. Before bevel
2. Wireframe after bevel applied
3. Shading after bevel applied.
   [image: 01 Shading Before Bevel]

[image: 02 Wireframe After Bevel Applied]

[image: 03 Shading After Bevel Applied]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I read similar problem on the below link:
[Material is stretching when using Edge Loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180619/material-is-stretching-when-using-edge-loop)
So, after beveling, with edges still selected I go to Mesh > Normals > Smooth Vectors
and then press Shift + r few times until ribs get smoother.
That's it.

Answer (score 1):

**There may be multiple reasons:**

---

1st: Did you apply scale for your object?

CTRL+A and choose scale(it will reset your dimensions to 1,1,1 but Blender will recalculate shading)

---

2nd: Is auto Smoothing enabled and set to good value?
[image]

---

3rd: If 2 solutions before didnt work, try to use Shift+N and recalculate outside

---

Question, are you using subdivision modifier right now? Bad topology may cause that shading as well if you use sub on it

After using bevel + smooth brush
[image]

Comment: Hello, Miko! 
I tried all 3 suggestions - it didn't help. Result is still same as from my result screen shot.
Subdivision modifier was already applied before, so its not in the stack anymore. Only modifier I have active now is mirror. I tried to apply it, but no effect.

Comment: is there possibility for me to look at it?

Comment: I did a small workaround, i deleted one loop cut and added 6 instead of it with smoothness value of 0,5. It gives a better result, but still i can see, that there is an "intervention" into the shape. It still visible that shading area is a bit different, however, with Zebra matcap You can't see a difference. If nothing works, I will go with this option. But I want to find out, why there is a problem in my original approach. Thank You!

Comment: It's weird, but with 2.92.3 I'm not seeing the problem.  You do have some non-quad faces in the vicinity of the wing outline and they're producing some shading issues but otherwise it looks fine on my monitor.

Comment: I am sorry for being late, I just opened it and I see no problem as well with your shading... I will add picture to my answer so that you can see

Comment: Sorry guys, i uploaded the file without beveling. It is my fault, somehow i thought it will be better to send file untouched. Can You please apply bevel on some of the loopcuts and share a screen shot?

Comment: Hmm okay there is a little deform visible on a plane after bevel but you can actually solve it really easy... just go to sculpt mode, take a smooth brush, set strength to 0.05-0.08, and go over all of it few times, it will not affect your geometry too much and it will smooth those lines... see picture of result

Comment: Thanks, man! Amazing one, didn't know i can do that! Again, the power of this site helps me to save time! Appreciate everyone's response!